# Understanding "avec, au-dehors, tout le plein du soleil"

Tags: prépositions, syntaxe

The question is on the highlighted phrase in this excerpt from Camus's The Stranger.

> Je peux dire qu’au fond l’été a très vite remplacé l’été. Je savais qu’avec la montée des premières chaleurs surviendrait quelque chose de nouveau pour moi. Mon affaire était inscrite à la dernière session de la cour d’assises et cette session se terminerait avec le mois de juin. Les débats se sont ouverts **avec, au-dehors, tout le plein du soleil.** Mon avocat m’avait assuré qu’ils ne dureraient pas plus de deux ou trois jours.

**Question**

What is the substantive that the preposition *avec* governs?

I thought of the following.  Please let me know if any of those is correct, or some other I haven't thought of

(a) *avec* governs *tout*, a pronoun meaning *everything.* *le plein du soleil* is an adjectival phrase modifying *tout*. So we have, in essence, *with the sun-full everything*.

(b) It governs *tout*, a pronoun, as in (a).  But *le plein du soleil* stands in apposition to *tout*.  Somewhat as in *Charles the Bold* or *Charles le Téméraire*. In *with Charles the Bold* we would say that *with* governed both *Charles* and *the Bold* (because they stand in apposition, whatever governs the one cannot fail to govern the other also). Likewise, we should say that *avec* governs both *tout* and *le plein de soleil*.

(c) It governs *soleil* somehow.  In this case, I don't know how to account for everything that lies between *avec* and *soleil*.

I realize that I may be straining things.  But I am asking a formal question.  Where there is a preposition, there must be a substantive it governs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without wishing to detract in any way from cl-r's answer (an answer that sent my eyes skittering, dancing over my shelves in search of my books by Camus), I'd like to try to reply in the vein the question is asked in, because to me the sentence makes perfect *grammatical* sense (even though I am not a real grammarian, just a dabbling amateur who thinks he knows it when he sees it).

"au-dehors" is an "adjectif de lieu", it specifies the location of the following noun. We can remove it from the grammatical equation.

The noun ("groupe nominal") that "avec" governs is "tout le plein du soleil", all of it, as a single grammatical group. If you want to decompose further, I'd say the base noun is "le plein", complemented by "du soleil", and further specified by "tout", in what order is probably immaterial.

In (somewhat) normal French "le plein" would probably be written "la plénitude", but that doesn't really change the grammar of it, and this is not run-of-the-mill French. "plein de soleil" would be even more run-of-the-mill and would change the meaning of "the sun" to "sunshine".

I'll very humbly propose the almost word-for-word translation "The debates opened, with, outside, all the fullness of the sun" (fullness=plénitude, full=plein).

Comment: Ah, thank you. I also want to appreciate the poetry as cl-r recommends, but at my level of French I could not even figure out how much of a poetic license the phrase represented (anywhere between perfectly grammatical and something wild). *le plein : la plénitude* was exactly the help I needed.

Answer (score 2):

***tout le plein du soleil*** peut théoriquement être découpé en vocables, mais c'est une *expression poétique* dont se sert Albert Camus pour exprimer sa sensibilité au soleil d'Algérie (Cf. Noces).

Il faut le lire comme une trouvaille pour exprimer que le soleil est au zénith, que dehors tout croule sous une lumière à la fois brûlante et vivifiante.

Si vous enlevez un seul mot de cette expression, l'intensité sensorielle évoquée disparaît.

*avec, dehors,* est lié à l'expression d'une sensation qui tient en cinq mots, et qui vient en contraste à ce qui se passe 'dedans'.

Bien que ce soit une lecture singulière et donc très personnelle, j'ai lu A.Camus en savourant ses expressions poétiques qui renvoient à quelque chose de vibrant, de lumineux, avec pour étendard : "la grammaire cède le pas devant l'expression poétique", d'ailleurs ne parle-t-on pas de *licence poétique* lorsque l'on 'tord' un peu les mots dans un poème, et de *pure poésie* lorsque l'expression résonne au plus profond de nous ?

Si vous étiquetez et privilégiez *tout, plein* ou *soleil*, voire *le* et *du*,  vous regardez un diamant par une facette et une seule à la fois en disant que c'est la seule possible, la seule correcte, vous ne verrez pas les lumières irisées qui ressortent par les autres facettes, ce qui est frustrant !
Alors que percevoir la totalité adamantine de la pierre est d'une toute autre puissance émotionnelle.

Comment: @Law29 -- Malgré plusieurs relectures, cela m'avait échappé :)

Comment: Ce n'est pas une raison de rajouter une croûte au lieu de changer Cf. en cf. :)

Comment: @Law29 -- Intéressant : à par la confusion entre *croûte* et *croule*, pour *Cf*, j'hésite : déplacer le point avant le symbole `(` et supprimer les parenthèses ? Cela casserait la fluidité de la phrase, j'ai essayé  un *tiret cadratin* « — »,U+2014, qui donne raison aux réducteurs de 'tête de mot'... mais, je l'ai trouvé tout riquiqui ! Le Robert indique que l'on peut écrire *Cf* ou *cf* ; une recherche Ngram "Cf., cf." (French + casse sensible) donne Cf. majoritaire : je maintiens donc les parenthèses  pour la grandeur de ce `C` :)